# Getting Instructors name by its subject_id

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys I am having problem on my mySQL query. Kindly see my tables and current query.

Table "instructors"

```
---------------------------------------------
id |firstname |     lastname    | subject_id|
---------------------------------------------
1    Juan         Dela Cruz            1
2    Antonio      Brigada              2
--------------------------------------------
```

Table "subjects"

```
---------------
id |   name   |
---------------
1    English
2    Math
3    Science
--------------
```

My current query

```
public function instructor(){
global $database;

$sql = "SELECT instructors.firstname as firstname, instructors.lastname as lastname ";
$sql .= "FROM subjects ";
$sql .= "JOIN instructors ";
$sql .= "WHERE subjects.id = instructors.subject_id";

$result = $database->query($sql);

while($instructor = $database->fetch_array($result)){
    if (isset($instructor['firstname']) && isset($instructor['lastname'])){
            return $instructor['lastname'] . " " . $instructor['firstname'];
    } else {
        return "N/A";
    }

    }
}
```

Result:

```
English    Juan Dela Cruz
Math       Juan Dela Cruz
Science    Juan Dela Cruz
```

**Edit**

Current sql:

```
public function instructor(){
global $database;

$sql = "SELECT  a.name, ";
$sql .= "COALESCE(CONCAT(b.firstname, ' ',b.lastname), 'N/A') as ins_name ";
$sql .= "FROM subjects a ";
$sql .= "LEFT JOIN instructors b ";
$sql .= "ON a.id = b.subject_id";

$result = $database->query($sql);

   while($instructor = $database->fetch_array($result)){
      return $instructor['ins_name'];
   }
}
```

Result

```
English    Juan Dela Cruz
Math       Juan Dela Cruz
Science    Juan Dela Cruz
```

What it should be:

```
English    Juan Dela Cruz
Math       Antonio Brigada
Science    N/A
```

Calling the instructor() function

```
<?php foreach($subjects as $subject): ;?>
  <tr class="subject_list">
    <td><?php echo $subject->name; ?></td> // This will show all subjects
    <td><?php echo $subject->instructor(); ?></td> // This will show instructor foreach subjects
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I hope anyone can help me to see the result above.

Comment: why `coalesce`? This looks like a pretty straight forward one to one relation.

Comment: @Starx

Even my first query isn't working. :(

Comment: @Starx because that was in johns example in his answer, and it wasn't one to one, that was the problem. the COALESCE was to get the N/A.

Comment: @arjay0601 how are you calling the instructor function in your php because it returns one column from one row but your results show two columns and multiple rows.

Comment: @marvin

post updated with calling my instructor() function

Comment: @Starx there are certain possibilities that a subject may not have instructor yet.

Answer (score 3):

`LEFT JOIN` is what you need

```
SELECT  a.name, 
        COALESCE(CONCAT(b.firstName, ' ',b.LastName), 'N/A')
FROM    subjects a
        LEFT JOIN instructors b
            ON a.ID = b.Subject_ID
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f7a9/1)

Comment: You're missing some of your code.  When you get the first record back it's returning out of the instructors function isn't it?

Comment: What I meant was I think that you need to post a little more of your code.  I think the problem is in your php because john's SQL is good.

Comment: @arjay0601 what are you getting now?

Comment: @JohnWoo

Same. Still Juan Delacruz for all subjects.
My post update about how I called the instructor() function. please see.

Comment: It is definitely your php. You never tell it which subject to get the instructor for.  So it's pulling back all of them and you are only returning the first answer each time.  You should make your SQL do the work and have your php output the results, not piece it together in your php.